# How to use a char array in java if the size is unknown?

Tags: java, arrays

If I don't know the size of array of chars I'm using, is there a way to use it without setting the size upfront ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can use a [`java.util.List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) when you don't know the size up front.

```
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
chars.add('f');
chars.add('o');
chars.add('o');
```

Depending on your needs, a [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) might make more sense than a `List<Character>`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append('f')
  .append('o')
  .append('o');
```

<s>If you want to get really slick, use [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) for its list-of-primitives so you can work with the (third-party equivalent of) a `List<char>`.</s> nevermind. Trove [does not have](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/index-files/index-17.html) a `TCharArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a String or a StringBuilder and then convert it to a char array later?